# Terminal output redirection not working for Caffe

Tags: neural-network, ubuntu-14.04, deep-learning, caffe, io-redirection

I want to redirect Caffe's output from the terminal to a file (say `output.txt`). I'm using the command

```
caffe train -solver=expt/solver.prototxt > output.txt`
```

However, the `>` operator doesn't seem to be working and Caffe spits out all the output on to the terminal. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Can't seem to figure out why `>` is not working with Caffe. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to [redierect stderr](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) as well

```
caffe train ... > output.txt 2>&1
```

The redirection operator `>` redirects only stdout, caffe is using sterr as well. You might want to set `GLOG_logtosterr=1` as well.